# IllegalArgumentException when compiling using TeaVM

Tags: gradle, teavm, teavm-flavour

I am trying to compile a Flavour project using TeaVM. I am going through [TeaVM Gradle plugin](https://github.com/vic-cw/teavm-gradle-plugin), and I am getting the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.Object is not subclass of ...`

I have tried running `./gradlew clean`, to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be due to an illegal state inside the TeaVM compiler.

To fix the situation, simply stop the Gradle daemons:

`./gradlew --stop`

Comment: Hi, are you still using TeaVM for your projects?

Comment: Hi there. Yes I am :)

Comment: I see, cool. However I don't think someone is maintaining here to support the `teavm` tag

Comment: Hold on a sec are you the "vic-cw" that's from TeaVM Google Groups?